# Does Algolia support Hebrew and morphology?

Tags: search-engine, hebrew, algolia

I want to index data in Hebrew and other languages (EN, RU, AR).
I need in my project morphology in those languages.
Does Algolia search support Hebrew language and Hebrew morphology?

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/which-languages-are-supported-by-the-engine

Answer (score 1):

The Algolia tokenizer is [language-agnostic](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/which-languages-are-supported-by-the-engine) and leverages the Unicode table and its extensions to deal with normalizations and expansions (like simplified<=>traditional chinese).

In addition to that:

- (native) prefix search capabilities
- automatic "plural<=>singular forms" [handling](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/how-does-ignoreplurals-work)
- edit distance-based typo-tolerance & split/concatenation of words [handling](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/how-do-you-handle-the-users-mistakes)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
I didn't found any documentation about Hebrew morphology...
Did the product support it?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any hebrew specific support. The native prefix search and word split/concatenation combined to an as-you-type search experience might be enough however.

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely that Algolia support Hebrew morphology as Hebrew has very complex structures. For example, each verb might have hundreds(!) of different forms- with no algorithm for extracting the lemma from it.
Look at the following forms of "walk": "כשהתהלכנו" mean: "when we were walking" while "מוליך" mean "he is walking the...".
Hence, just the task of lemmatizing a word is very complex, and this is just a prefix to handling Hebrew.
Note: I couldn't find any reference for Hebrew morphology on Algolia documentation, so it's better to contact them for further information.